# Java While loop extra conditions

Tags: java, while-loop, conditional-statements, equals

In JavaScript you can add extra conditions like:

```
var b = 0.0;
var q = (void 0);
var e = -1.0;

while(q = e, b > 32.0){

    console.log(q);
    b++;

}
```

Meaning that q equals to e.

I have tried to rephrase Java code to

```
Float b = 0.0;
Float q = Float.NaN;
Float e = -1.0;

do{

    q = e;
    b++;

}while(b < 32.0);
```

But it seems that it doesn't work as JS version.

Can I just add q = e to while conditions? Is there any valid Java syntax for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) in Java, and even if there was, it would be considered bad style.

There are ways you can achieve similar things. If you define a function that takes any parameter and always returns true:

```
<T> boolean trick(T any) {
    return true;
}
```

you can use it to sneak in assignment expressions in any boolean context you want:

```
while (trick(q = e) && b > 32.0){
    System.out.println(q);
    b++;
}
```

But again, this would be considered *terrible* style. Don't use this in a real project.

Comment: An elegant solution! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't have a hyperflexible comma operator like JavaScript so you'll have to split the statements apart. That's not a bad thing. `while(q = e, b > 32.0)` is poor style.

Stick with a regular `while` loop. A `do-while` loop won't do because it'll always execute `b++` at least once.

I would use `double` rather than `float`.

```
double b = 0.0;
double q;
double e = -1.0;

q = e;
while (b < 32.0) {
    b++;
    q = e;
}
```

And we might as well initialize `q` when it's declared:

```
double b = 0.0;
double e = -1.0;
double q = e;

while (b < 32.0) {
    b++;
    q = e;
}
```